# The problem is when changing the proxy type to ajax in Ext.data.Store on ExtJs

Tags: javascript, python, django, extjs

My problem is when I change the type in the Store to ajax.
The store in my application looked like this:

```
var urlRoot = 'data?model=Operation&method=';

    Ext.define('BookApp.store.BookStore', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        model: 'BookApp.model.Book',
        autoLoad: true,
        storeId: 'BookStore',
        proxy: {
                type: 'jsonp',
                noCache: false,
                api: {
                    create:     urlRoot + 'Create',
                    read:       urlRoot + 'Read',
                    update:     urlRoot + 'Update',
                    destroy:    urlRoot + 'Destroy'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    metaProperty: 'meta',
                    rootProperty: 'data',
                    idProperty: 'id',
                    totalProperty: 'meta.total',
                    successProperty: 'meta.success'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json',
                    encode: true,
                    writeAllFields: true,
                    rootProperty: 'data',
                    allowSingle: false

                }
            }
    });
```

When I change the store type to ajax

```
.....
proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',

            .....
```

then when I download the application I get error 500 (Internal Server Error)
I know that the jsonp type is required to load data from another domain on which my application is running, but I have the entire application and the database included, is on the same local machine, so I set the type of ajax. But with this type a problem arises.

On the backend side, the answer is as follows:

```
...
# Form the answer
dict_out= {"data" : list, "meta": { "success": "true", "msg": "", "total": str(count) }}
# Translate it into the format Json
jsonFormat = json.dumps(dict_out)
# Add to the answer callback
read_out = dict['callback'] +'(' + jsonFormat + ')'
return HttpResponse(read_out)
....
```

Error in browser
[image]

Why can this problem occur?

Thank you

Comment: An error 500 ("Internal Server Error") occurs at will of your web server, mostly due to configuration error or script/program execution error. The server may or may not provide you with information as to where and why the error occurred, for example in ASP.NET, many are caused by uncaught null reference exceptions. Check the returned text in the network tab.

Comment: @ Alexander thank you so much. In the server response I saw the following:
MultiValueDictKeyError at / data "'callback'"
and I noticed that my answer is not correct:
read_out = dict ['callback'] + '(' + jsonFormat + ')'
After I corrected the answer to:
  read_out = '(' + jsonFormat + ')'
the error was gone.